# Apache ActiveMQ Server-to-Server connection

Tags: activemq, message-queuing, messaging

Our company now uses Websphere MQ to facilitate communication with our business partners, but we're evaluating migration to ActiveMQ. I've read some documentation and articles and haven't found particular option we need - server-to-server connections.

Apache MQ has notion of broker networks, but as I understood it's more of a clustering then site-to-site communication.

We need to have a local message broker (AMQ server) and a remote one. Local is used by our applications and remote one is used by our partner's apps, there is a limited number of remote queues (on partner's broker) we need to put messages to and we also have some queues on our side which our partners have to put messages to. Is there a possibility to implement this workload with ApacheMQ?

From what I've read in the documentation the broker networks and distributed queues are a clustering solution to load balance messages between [geographically or otherwise] separated brokers. This presents HUGE security problems in our case.

Let's imagine we have two partners - A and B. we need to send messages to queue a.receive.q and b.receive.q on A and B respectively. From what I read A actually can subscribe to b.receive.q and vice versa. Also, if some hostile employee on our side (consider this just for the sake of risk assessment) launches local consumer on a.receive.q, messages won't be sent over the network at all (or only a fraction will be sent).

Feel free to ask questions if I'm a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was absolutely correct, websphere-like server-to-server workflow is not a part of ActiveMQ's feature set.